# NameError: global name 'This_is_a_Function_Name' is not defined

Tags: python

I am having a function called `downloadfile` so i type in the Shell:

```
>>> import mod3
>>> from mod3 import downloadfile
```

It is important to bear in mind that the `downloadfile` function is being used inside another function called `vario`.

Following the typical procedure:

```
>>> import mod2
>>> from mod2 import vario
```

The function `vario` has the following code:

```
def vario(feed):
    import df
    for item in feed.entries: #change feed to the name e.g. g = feedparser.parse('RSS-URL') change it to g
        print( item[ "summary" ], item[ "title" ], item[ "published" ] )
        # Identify ZIP file enclosure, if available
        enclosures = [ l for l in item[ "links" ] if l[ "rel" ] == "enclosure" ] # it's saying take every l, where the 'rel' value is 'enclosure'
        if ( len( enclosures ) > 0 ):
            # ZIP file enclosure exists, so we can just download the ZIP file
            enclosure = enclosures[0]
        sourceurl = enclosure[ "href" ]
        cik = item[ "edgar_ciknumber" ]
        targetfname = df.target_dir+cik +' - ' +sourceurl.split('/')[-1] #df.target_dir change made
        retry_counter = 3
        while retry_counter > 0:
            good_read = downloadfile( sourceurl, targetfname ) # go and write the downloadfile function!
            if good_read:
                break
            else:
                print( "Retrying:", retry_counter )
                retry_counter -= 1
```

But I am confronted with this error whenever i try to `>>> vario(g)` with g the name of the feed I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#24>", line 1, in <module>
    contie(g)
  File "E:\Py_env\df2.py", line 15, in contie
    good_read = downloadfile( sourceurl, targetfname ) # go and write the downloadfile function!
NameError: global name 'downloadfile' is not defined
```

I am unable to understand how a function that has been imported and had even the module containing her imported cannot operate. Can you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functions look up globals *in the module they are defined in*. In other words, globals are only visible *per module*.

Add `from mod3 import downloadfile` to the source of `mod2`.

Your Python interpreter session is it's own module (it has a global namespace too), so if you copy and paste the `vario()` function into your interpreter session, it'll use the globals there instead.